# Laravel can't read database credential form .env file

Tags: laravel-5.1

php artisan migrate

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

.env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=JYi8UKIIoaXlU9vrkNkrpu0Y7VpkaA3X

DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=homestead

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

I did't make any change in database.php

```
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
```

When i run: php artisan env

it show local if i change env to production it show production .
I do't understand why mysql won't work.

Also in front end show:

> Whoops, looks like something went wrong.

Laravel error page show like production environment.
In apache error log have't any error.

I am stuck with this problem.
I change file permission clear laravel cache.I can't make it working.I am using vagrant . New laravel installation works fine.
Please help me.

Comment: Are you really using 'Homestad'?  What you are showing here is the Laravel default configuration which you need to change with your own database credentials.

Comment: thanks for response.I am using ubuntu/trusty64 with apache server. database name homestad

Comment: But you are using the default credentials in the '.env' file. You need to change those values with your database connection credentials. At least if the one you are showing are your real credential which I do not it is.

Comment: My above database credential is ok. I guess laravel only read first line of my env file.

Comment: I am install new laravel 5.1 and copy all file to new installation it's works fine. I have backup error one. I want to find the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might have cached the config. Try running `artisan config:clear` or `artisan config:cache` on production.

`artisan config:clear` will remove any cache you might have and start using your .env instead. This is obviously non-optimal on a production server and is the reason for the `config:cache` command.

Comment: thank you very much. It's works. First i was clear only cache Did't clear config :)

Comment: Yeah this did my head in enough times to have finally stuck.

Comment: Thanks, `config:clear` saved me a life from sporadically unavailable config values.